# Microsoft Endpoint Manager Firewall rule not working

Tags: windows-firewall, microsoft-intune

I am trying to use Microsoft Endpoint Manager to block all traffic to Microsoft Edge for a group. I have done the following:

- Created a group called Students and added user "Zephyr Prospect" (not a real person)
- Created an endpoint protection firewall profile
- added that profile to the students group
- Added a Microsoft Defender Firewall configuration to the profile
- Added a Firewall Rule to the configuration. In the rule I have the following:

Rule settings:

- Direction: inbound
- Action: Block
- Network Type: 0 selected
- Application: Package family name
- Package Family name: Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe (got this from Get-AppXPackage)
- Local Address: any address
- Remote address: any address
- Protocol: any
- Interface types: 0 selected

But the student in the group can still connect with Edge. I tried changing direction to Outbound as well.

How do I get this rule to work?

Comment: Shouldn't your rule target the executable msedge.exe?

Comment: There are 2 ways to do it. You can use the file path. But I can't count on the file path being the same for every computer. But you are also supposed to be able to do the "package family name" which refers to that application, which you can get through Get-AppXPackage in powershell.

Comment: Is there an option to target the Name (**Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge**) or PackageFullName (**Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_44.19041.1266.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe**)?

Comment: No. The two options are Package Family Name and file path.

Answer (score 2):

The direction of the rule must be "Outbound" if you want to prevent Edge from connecting to something.

Application: Do not use `Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe` because this refers to the old Edge browser, this browser is not supported anymore. You should use the [latest Edge browser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge) (chromium based), then, specify the File Path.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this on Monday; if it works I'll check it.